# Javascript Click Event Listener not firing but has been added to button

Tags: javascript, shopify, event-listener

Hoping someone can help me here because I can't figure out what's going on

I'm trying to add an event listener to this Shopify Add to Cart button, in Firefox I can see that the 'click' event is being added to button, however the code isn't being fired

Code I'm using and have used many times for other small scripts

Update - Seems like it's caused because of the `type="submit"` but that's needed, so I'm not sure how to work around it

```
const addToCartButton = document.querySelector('[data-add-to-cart]');

addToCartButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('clicked')
});
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It is extremely difficult to help without seeing code that shows the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Unmitigated that fixed the issue, completely overlooked that solution

Really appreciate it mate 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`"mousedown"` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) instead.

```js
addToCartButton.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
  console.log('mousedown')
});
```